# Using Strcmp in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to search for key words from  in a text document I have tried to exclude white space, new lines, and tabs. I am able to read inputs from the file but I can not get my strcmp and the counter to change. I tried to use printf statements to locate the issue but I am still lost. If  its a syntax issue let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

Heres the block of code

```
FILE *file2 = fopen( argv[2], "r");

if (file2 == NULL) {
    printf("\nFile 2 could not open\n");
} else {
    do {
        // treat all new line as spaces.   
        x = fgetc( file2 );

        if (x == '\n') {
            x = 32;
        }

        if (x == '\t') {
            x = 32;
        }

        if(x != 32 ) {
            temp[l] = x;

        } else { 
            temp[l] == '\0';

            printf("\t%s", temp);

            for(a=0; a < countw; a++) {
                p = strcmp(swords[a].word,temp);
                if (p = 0) {
                    swords[a].count++;
                }
                printf("\nstop%i\n",a);
            }

            for(b=0; b<l; b++) {
                temp[b] = '\0';
            }
            l = 0; 
        }
    } while (x != EOF);
}

fclose(file2);
```

Answer (score 4):

It think your problem is right here:

```
if(p = 0 )
```

It should be:

```
if(p == 0 )
```

Turn up your compiler warning level enough (like `-Wall` in gcc) and you may get a warning for unintended assignments.

Comment: Another good way to avoid accidental assignment of constants is to reverse the order. `if( 0 == p )` is logically the same, but if you leave out one `=` then it will not compile. Alternatively, in this instance, you don't need `p` and can just write `if( strcmp( swords[a].word, temp ) == 0 )`

Comment: @ChrisRyding: Opinions differ on whether [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) are a *good* way to avoid this error. Personally I find `if (0 == p)` jarring and counterintuitive.

Comment: I have  tried it both ways, neither cause the counter in increment. Maybe its because I am using a struct??

Comment: @ChrisRyding: Perhaps this was a good idea in the 1990's, but now any good compiler will issue a warning if it encounters expressions like `if (p = 0)` (provided you've turned on checking options, which you should do anyway), so there is no point reversing the evaluation order, except if you intend to make your intent less clear or want your fellow programmers to hate you.

Comment: I find it a bit jarring myself, just used to work with a (very) senior developer who always swore by the technique.